# How to get the `self` to refer to a my class inside a Mixin module (even if it is stated outside the context of a method)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module, mixins

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2. I have implemented a Mixin module for a `Article` model class and I would like to get the `self` to refer to `Article` (even, for example, if it stated outside the context of a method). That is, I am trying to make the following:

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # Note: The following is just a sample code (it doesn't work for what I am 
  # trying to accomplish) since 'self' isn't referring to Article but to the
  # MyModule itself.
  include MyModule::AnotherMyModule if self.my_article_method?

  ...
end
```

The above code generates the following error:

```
undefined method `my_article_method?' for MyModule
```

How can I run the `my_article_method?` in the above so that the `self` (or something else) refers to the `Article` model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Concern`'s `included` method instead:

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include MyModule::AnotherModule if self.my_article_method?
  end
end
```

Comment: By using your code I get `undefined method 'my_article_method?' for #<Class:0x000001039d2688>`, even if when I try to `raise("#{self}")` (inside the `included do ... end` block) I get the `Article` class name.

Comment: Are you including it in classes other than Article that don't have a class method `my_article_method?`?

Comment: No, all classes that include the `MyModule` module respond to the `my_article_method?` method.

Comment: Ok, is the line `include MyModule` before `def self.my_article_method?` in your classes? If so, move it after.

Comment: To make things to work, by moving the `include MyModule` after the `def self.my_article_method?` statement as you suggest, I have to use `include MyModule::AnotherModule if self.new.my_article_method?` (note the `new`) inside the `included do ... end` block... ***why?!*** More, in general, is it "correct" / "right" to have these "before-after dependencies" in classes?

Comment: If you have to use `new` then `my_article_method?` is an instance method (`def my_article_method?`), not a class method (`def self.my_article_method?`).

Comment: Ops! It was my fault for the class-instance method "awareness"... and about the other "sub-question" in the previous comment: *In general, is it "correct" / "right" to have these "before-after dependencies" in classes?*

Comment: It's pretty hard to say. To do what you are asking in the original question, then yes, you have to `include` the module after you `def` the method. "Is this a good idea?" is a whole other question - you might want to ask that separately :)

Comment: In a few I will post a new "dedicated" question for that (I will alert you when I have done), but I am in trouble when I have to set question *tags*...

Comment: I opened an [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641917/is-it-a-good-idea-to-make-statements-to-depend-on-the-order-of-other-statements) relating the order of statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `self.included` hook:

```
def self.included(klass)
  klass.include MyModule::AnotherMyModule if klass.my_article_method?
end
```

I'd rather put the logic on the actual `Article` class. The module shouldn't need to know about the classes it is included in:

```
class Article
  include MyModule
  include MyModule::AnotherModule if self.my_article_method?
end
```

Comment: By using your code I cannot use anymore the *useful* and *convenient* `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` statement. What do you think about?

Comment: is `Article.my_article_method?` constant at runtime?

Comment: Yes (it should). I also am trying to move the `include` statement "under" the `included do ... end` block provided by `ActiveSupport::Concern`, but without success: I am getting `undefined method 'my_article_method?' for #<Class:0x000001039d2688>`.

Comment: I would like to `include` the `AnotherModule` from `MyModule` because the logic "depends" more on `MyModule` than the `Article` class.