# Is it a good idea to make statements to depend on the order of other statements?

Tags: ruby, module, include

After a [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640645/how-to-get-the-self-to-refer-to-a-my-class-inside-a-mixin-module-even-if-it-i/12640884), an answer ([@Andy H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725792/andy-h)) said that the related problem was the order of statements. So, in general, *is it "correct" / "right" to have "before-after statement dependencies"?* That is, for example, if I have the following *working* code

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list ...

  include MyModule
end
```

and the following code does *not* work

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base      
  include MyModule

  acts_as_list ...
end
```

Is there some "bad" reason to do not continue the implementation of the class? That is, in general, *is that a good idea to make statements to depend on the order of other statements?*

Comment: why don't you add the `acts_s_list` behaviour from the module since they are tied?

Comment: @apneadiving: sometimes you include a module that depends on custom implementation of some methods in the class (example: `<=>` and `Enumerable`), there is nothing wrong with it in principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not a question of "good" vs "bad".

It just happens to be the case that code gets executed from top down.

So if you have some code in `statement_a` that relies on behaviour added by `statement_b` then putting `statement_b` before `statement_a` is the only solution...

Answer (score 0):

1. In your case: yes, it's not acceptable. Conceptually the order is not important there, it's the implementation which is forcing a fixed order to work. Not nice.
2. In general: Of course in a non-lazy language like Ruby the order of statements matter. But it's not the same the order "dependency" in `x = 1; y = 2 * x` that one that involves state and side-effects (silly example: `x = []; x << 1 if condition1?; x << 2 if condition2?; x`).